# ESP32 start BLE after deep sleep

Tags: bluetooth, nodemcu, esp32, ble

I'm new to using the esp32 as a microcontroller. I'm currently working on a so-to-say remote control. Since I want to use the esp32 with an external battery I need to put it in deep-sleep after I pressed some buttons to preserve battery.

All that works fine I've connected a small touchpad to put the esp32 into deep sleep mode using the `esp_deep_sleep_start()` function . The controller itself goes to sleep and can be woken up using the following 2 lines:

```
  touchAttachInterrupt(T0, wakeCallback, TOUCH_THRESHOLD);
  esp_sleep_enable_touchpad_wakeup();
```

In order to communicate with my Raspberry Pi 'Base Station' I decided to use BLE.
My server is configured the following way (where `bleServer`, `bleCharacteristic` and `bleService` are global variables):

```
  BLEDevice::init("esp-32-remote");
  bleServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  bleServer->setCallbacks(new ServerCallbacks());

  bleService = bleServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  bleCharacteristic = bleService->createCharacteristic(
                        CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                      );

  bleCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());
  bleService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
```

Upon regular restart using the buttons everything works fine. I can connect to the device using python and the bluepy library.

If I now wake the controller I can't do anything anymore. The `setup()` function gets called and there are no errors, nor does the controller crash due to any code errors (seemingly).

Then the loop function gets called once, and thats it. I can't connect to the device anymore until I press the hardware reset button.

The questions that arise are:

- might there be some error in the way I shutdown the bluetooth module?
- Does the loop function work after being woken up from deep sleep?

Maybe one of you has an idea regarding my issue. If there are more information that I need to provide, don't hesitate to tell me, I'm new to the whole mcu topic and I don't know whats best to provide here.

Answer (score 2):

Does the loop function work after being woken up from deep sleep? YES

loop function isn't magical.  its just a function that gets called over and over.  In other words, if it gets called once, it can be called again except if

- it did something to deactivate itself
- never reached the end

during that first call.  Check that you are not activating some sort of state inside the loop or going into a blocking call awaiting a signal that is never sent.

For good measure, make sure to reset all your variables to their expected states - expecting something to be 0 or set via the original definition may be insufficient.  This is something that occurs on a power reset so if reset is making it work again, thats a likely culprit.  Use a bare minimum of code in the loop for debug so you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll look into that.
Do you have any recommendation regarding the BLE issue?

Comment: I do not at this time.  I did read that a "the TV Begone remote control" intentionally went to a sleep without wake upon sending a power off signal, and tied into the reset button for waking again, so be careful what you copy and from where.  https://www.gammon.com.au/power

Answer (score 0):

There's a good tutorial [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ble-server-client/) on how to connect the BLE server client to the ESP32. And a Good fix [here](https://stuvel.eu/post/2022-05-01-esp32-ble-advertisement-fixed/) for reconnection issues.

Below is a piece of prototype code I wrote for BLE server client connectivity:

```
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
      deviceDisconnected=false;
      interface->onBoardLED->led[0] = interface->onBoardLED->LED_GREEN;
      interface->onBoardLED->statusLED(100, 1);
      BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
      interface->onBoardLED->led[0] = interface->onBoardLED->LED_BLUE;
      interface->onBoardLED->statusLED(100, 1);
      interface->onBoardLED->led[0] = interface->onBoardLED->LED_BLUE;
      interface->onBoardLED->statusLED(100, 1);
      interface->onBoardLED->led[0] = interface->onBoardLED->LED_BLUE;
      interface->onBoardLED->statusLED(100, 1);
      pServer->getAdvertising()->start();
    }
};

class pCharacteristicTX_Callbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();
    
      if (rxValue.length() > 0) {
        String msg="";
        mserial->printStrln("*********");
        mserial->printStr("Received Value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++) {
           msg=msg+String(rxValue[i]);
           mserial->printStr(String(rxValue[i])); 
        } 
      
        mserial->printStrln(""); 
        mserial->printStrln("*********");

        //valueReceived=msg;
      } 
    }

    void onRead(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      mserial->printStrln("*********");
      mserial->printStr("onRead...");    
      pCharacteristic->setValue("OK");
    }

  }; 
                    
class pCharacteristicRX_Callbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      
      mserial->ble=false;

      if (rxValue.length() > 0) {
        String msg="";
        mserial->printStr("Received Value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rxValue.length(); i++) {
           msg=msg+String(rxValue[i]);
           mserial->printStr(String(rxValue[i])); 
        } 
      
        msg.trim();
        $BLE_CMD=msg;
        mserial->ble=true;
        newCMDarrived=true;
      }
    } 

    void onRead(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      mserial->printStrln("*********");
      mserial->printStr("onRead...");    
      pCharacteristic->setValue("OK");
    }

  }; 

//------------------------------------------------------------------


// Create the BLE Device 
  BLEDevice::init("Smart Concrete Curing");  // Give it a name 
  
  // Create the BLE Server 
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer(); 
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create the BLE Service
  pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  
  // Create a BLE Characteristic

  pCharacteristicTX = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                    );


  pCharacteristicTX->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  pCharacteristicRX = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                    );

  pCharacteristicTX->setCallbacks(new pCharacteristicTX_Callbacks());
  pCharacteristicRX->setCallbacks(new pCharacteristicRX_Callbacks());

  interface->init_BLE(pCharacteristicTX);

  // Start the service
  pService->start();
```

on this particular code, I'm using light sleep , so to go to sleep :

```
      btStop();
      delay(1000);
      WiFi.disconnect(true);
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);

      changeMcuFreq(interface, interface->MIN_MCU_FREQUENCY);
```

and to wake up :

```
changeMcuFreq(interface, interface->WIFI_FREQUENCY);
btStart();
```